# Elit Scelerisque Mauris Pellentesque Pulvinar - Could some one please help to translate this

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, latin-to-english-translation

Could someone please help to transtale "Elit Scelerisque Mauris Pellentesque Pulvinar" to English?

Many thanks and best regards, 
Phuong

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where did you find this phrase? Do you know what it's context? All that kind of information helps us figure out whether it's right, what it's supposed to mean, and what it actually means.

Comment: Many thanks, Joonas Ilmavirta. I really appreciate your kind regard. Actually I have no idea about the context of this phrase. It was sent out/shared about a colleague as a sort of challenge.

Comment: *Pulvinar* is a significant couch, either a wedding couch or a shelf for statues at a feast. *Mauris* is a personal name which may be connected to the Moors, Mauritius, mulberries. *Scelus* is a crime, *sceleris* crimes, or of a crime. *Pellens* means driving, herding.

Comment: Feeding *Lorem ipsum* into the search box in the top margin leads to an earlier discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

**"Lorem ipsum"** is the name for a class of text used by printers and book designers to facilitate the layout of a Page. The fact that it has no meaning helps focus attention on, say, margins and the weight of the type chosen for headings and footnotes. Printers believe that it comes from a speech by Cicero; but if so it has been so hacked about and reassembled as to have no meaning and little connection.

This particular example comes, I think, from **[freeonlinetools24.com › blog › the-handy-lorem-ipsum-...](http://freeonlinetools24.com/blog/the-handy-lorem-ipsum-dolor-blind-text/)** but the single Transposition of "Elit" rescues it from plagiarism.

> Est ultricies integer quis auctor **elit** sed vulputate mi sit.
>   Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Gravida arcu ac
>   tortor dignissim convallis. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Commodo
>   ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis
>   imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem.
>   Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. **Scelerisque mauris
>   pellentesque pulvinar** pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
>   senectus. Adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
>   senectus. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing. Pretium viverra
>   suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor. A arcu cursus vitae congue
>   mauris rhoncus aenean.

It is particularly useful when an illustration is floated into a body of text.

**Correction:** Here is a good concise piece on *Lorem ipsum* from ['Open Culture.'](http://www.openculture.com/2015/03/the-story-of-lorem-ipsum.html)

Comment: Dear Hugh, Many thanks for your informative and detail reply. I really appreciate your kind regards. Best.

Comment: @PhuongNguyen If you liked the answer and think it addresses the question, please click the little V-shaped near the top left of the answer to indicate it as "accepted". Thanks!

Comment: He must have bailed, but +1 for a good answer.